# How to export D3js Bar Chart race to MP4/ Video

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]
var race = d3.interval(function() {}, tickDuration);

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on these resources:

- [renderd3-video](https://github.com/russellgoldenberg/render-d3-video)
- [D3 to MP4 using google puppeteer](https://roadtolarissa.com/d3-mp4/)

Comment: Is puppeteer a must? I managed to get this to work, but unsure about barchart race yet https://gist.github.com/Fil/f791ca9c519f718c72fc02dc1850ff0d